# Size of class containing object of another class

Tags: c++, class, sizeof

I am not able to get how class size is determined. sizeof(User) is 12 ? Can anyone pl. explain the reason behind it?

```
class dob
{
public:
    int dd;
        dob(){}
    dob(int d)
    {
        dd = d;
    }

};
class User
{
public:
    int Id;char Name;dob d;
    User(int id, dob i, char name)
    {
        Id = id;
        d = i;
        Name = name;
    }
};
```

Comment: what do you expect? 9? It is because of padding.

Comment: The size is the sum of the size of embedded data plus padding for non aligned data. So 4 for `Id`, 1+3 for `Name` and 4 for `d`.

Answer (score 2):

The size of a class is at least as large as the total size of its members; it may also include padding to give each member its required alignment.

Presumably, for you, `int` is four bytes, and has an alignment requirement of four bytes. So three bytes are added after the `char` member to give the required alignment, giving a total size of 12 bytes.

Polymorphic classes, and classes with virtual base classes, might contain extra "hidden" data to support these things, but that's not the case for your classes.